# glm::rotate() changes the rotation axis, but why?

Tags: c++, glm-math

Easy test code

```cpp
glm::mat4 m = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), 0.78f, glm::vec3(0,1,0));

while (true) {
    glm::vec3 axis = glm::normalize(glm::vec3(m[0]));  // right vector
    PRINT_VEC("{0:.3f} {1:.3f} {2:.3f}", axis.x, axis.y, axis.z);
    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(5.f), axis);  // 5 degrees each iteration
}
```

So, assume that I have a model matrix rotated from identity by 0.78 radians around the y axis, then every frame I'm going to rotate around the local right vector, which is the first column of the matrix (assume a right-handed system). Since the right vector is the axis around which I rotate, I expect it to be constant, but that's not true. I don't understand why `glm::rotate` also changes the rotation axis.

The output changes quite drastically so I don't think it's floating point precision errors.

```cpp
0.657 -0.424 -0.623
0.643 -0.482 -0.595
0.626 -0.539 -0.563
0.608 -0.593 -0.527
0.588 -0.646 -0.487
0.566 -0.696 -0.442
0.543 -0.742 -0.393
0.518 -0.785 -0.339
0.491 -0.824 -0.281
0.464 -0.858 -0.219
0.435 -0.887 -0.153
0.406 -0.910 -0.084
0.377 -0.926 -0.012
0.347 -0.936 0.063
0.319 -0.937 0.140
0.292 -0.931 0.218
0.267 -0.917 0.296
0.244 -0.895 0.374
0.224 -0.864 0.450
0.208 -0.826 0.524
```

Comment: Please care about the tags. [tag:glm] (generalized linear models) != [tag:glm-math] (GLM - OpenGL Mathematics). Note that you can click on a tag to see what it is about.

Comment: @Rabbid76 wow that's a subtle diff I didn't noticed, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`m[0]` isn't truly the 'local right vector'. It is the right vector in **world** coordinates. The right vector in **local** coordinates is `vec3(1,0,0)`, which is what you should use to achieve the desired rotation:

```
glm::mat4 m = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), 0.78f, glm::vec3(0,1,0));

while (true) {
    glm::vec3 axis = glm::normalize(glm::vec3(m[0]));  // right vector
    PRINT_VEC("{0:.3f} {1:.3f} {2:.3f}", axis.x, axis.y, axis.z);
    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(5.f), glm::vec3(1,0,0));  // 5 degrees each iteration
}
```

Prints:

```
0.711 0.000 -0.703
0.711 0.000 -0.703
0.711 0.000 -0.703
...
```

Note that GLM transformation functions, like `glm::rotate`, apply the transformation on the right; i.e.

```
m = m * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(5.f), axis);
```

And they expect the axis to be in the pre-transformation coordinate system -- i.e. the local one. Your code, instead, transforms the vector `vec3(1,0,0)` into the world coordinate system, and then applies a local rotation around a local vector that has those numeric coordinates, which turns out to be an arbitrary vector.

You can, in fact, use the `axis` in world space to perform the same rotation. However, you'd need to manually multiply on the left:

```
m = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(5.f), axis) * m;
```

which gives the same result as the first version above.

**EDIT:** Column vectors rendered using the correct vs incorrect code:

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's it! Turns out I failed to understand the "local space" vs "world space" difference when working with up/right/forward vectors. Thank you for your clear answer, I've fixed several mistakes in my code now.

Answer (score 1):

As @Yakov pointed out, my mistake was that I confused "local space" vs "world space". For those of you who encountered the same problem, what you need is a convertion between the two spaces. In summary, local rotation should be applied on the right, while global rotation should be applied on the left, we should explicitly specify the order of multiplication to prevent bugs.

```cpp
if (local) {  // local space
    // using matrix
    glm::mat4 R = glm::rotate(radians, v); // rotation matrix4x4
    m = m * R;  // applied on the right

    // using quaternion
    glm::quat Q = glm::angleAxis(radians, v);  // rotation quaternion
    q = q * Q;  // applied on the right
}
else {  // world space
    // using matrix
    glm::mat4 R = glm::rotate(radians, v);     // rotation matrix4x4
    m = R * m;  // applied on the left

    // using quaternion
    glm::quat Q = glm::angleAxis(radians, v);  // rotation quaternion
    q = Q * q;  // applied on the left
}
```

To convert the vector (rotation axis) between world space and local space, do:

```cpp
world_v = m * local_v;  // using matrix
world_v = q * local_v;  // using quaternion

local_v = glm::inverse(m) * world_v;  // using matrix
local_v = glm::inverse(q) * world_v;  // using quaternion
```

So for example, if `m[0] = (0.711, 0.000,-0.703)` is the right direction vector in world space, it will be `glm::inverse(m) * m[0] = (1,0,0)` in local space, so if you want a local rotation around it, you would do

```cpp
m = m * glm::rotate(radians, glm::inverse(m) * m[0]);
```

If the 4x4 matrix is orthogonal (without non-uniform scaling...), we can replace `glm::inverse(m)` with `glm::tranpose(m)`, which gives the same result but is computationally much cheaper, o/w we can't avoid an inverse operation. In comparison, calculating the inverse of a quaternion is very cheap since `glm::inverse(q)` only need a dot product of `vec4`, so a quaternion-based convertion is better.